# Polymer and WebComponentsReady event

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

According to the [Polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#WebComponentsReady), the `WebComponentsReady` event is necessary because...

> The polyfills parse element definitions and handle their upgrade asynchronously. If you prematurely fetch the element from the DOM before it has a chance to upgrade, you’ll be working with an HTMLUnknownElement. In these situations, wait for the WebComponentsReady event before interacting with the element

I have an HTML page that imports a single web component and registers a handler that logs a statement when all web components are loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="elements/my-element.html">
    </head>
    <body unresolved>
        <my-element></my-element>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
                console.log('components ready');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Why is the `WebComponentsReady` event firing before my-element's `ready` polymer event?** I need to know when I can interact with the custom element, e.g. change its properties and call its public methods.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Polymer 1.0 you can just listen for `WebComponentsReady`.

In Polymer 0.5, because it does more things asynchronously, there's an extra event called `polymer-ready` which will fire when your elements are loaded. Here's [a jsbin showing the order](http://jsbin.com/teyoj/2/edit).

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. Working perfectly.

Comment: Fwiw, `WebComponentsReady` is still fired by the CustomElements polyfill for the reasons given in the OP. This is useful when using CustomElements polyfill on it's own.    
    
Also fwiw, Polymer uses separate `polymer-ready` event mostly to support components using remote style-sheets without FOUC.

Comment: I have the same issue, but because I insert my custom elements after ```polymer-ready ``` fired, I can't use it and I need to listen to individual elements ready event. Unfortunately these element's don't have a ready function at that point ```(e.g myElement.ready(doSomething()) )``` because polyfills add these methods later. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Only WebComponentsReady is raised, now.

Comment: To add on to what @Nikolay mentioned, Polymer 1.0 [removed the `polymer-ready` event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#polymer-ready) and now you only needs to listen to `WebComponentsReady`