# Web Components: executing code on the <content> added

Tags: web-component

I have been tinkering with web components, and I had the idea to make a `<slide-show>` component that would work with this syntax:

```
<slide-show>
    <img src="...."/>
    <img src="...."/>
    <img src="...."/>
    <img src="...."/>
</slide-show>
```

For this, I took a code that was already working, and tried to separate it into a template. A **first draft** that worked perfectly was this:

**Index.html**

```
<slide-show></slide-show>
```

**slideshow.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="slide-show" attributes="foo">
    <template>
        <div style="width:500px;">
            <div id="slides">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=6">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=7">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=8">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=9">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Polymer('slide-show', {
            foo: 'bar',
            ready: function(){
                $(this.$.slides).slidesjs({ });
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**But when** I tried to move the elements outside the template, it is when things went wrong:

**Index.html**

```
<slide-show>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=7">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=8">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=9">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=0">
</slide-show>
```

**slideshow.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="slide-show" attributes="foo">
    <template>
        <div style="width:500px;">
            <div id="slides">
                <content></content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Polymer('slide-show', {
            foo: 'bar',
            ready: function(){
                $(this.$.slides).slidesjs({ });
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

In this case, the slideshow behaves "weirdly". Maybe it is that I have not understand correctly how the `<content>` tag works. What is wrong in my coding?

Comment: Hey, could you provide a JSFiddle or Plunk, so it's easier to debug?

Comment: Is it possible to import components with JSFiddle? Im not sure I can recreate imports on JSFiddle...

Comment: If you've found the answer on the possibility of importing components with jsfiddle let me know!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listening to a polymer attached event from outside that element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309771/listening-to-a-polymer-attached-event-from-outside-that-element)