# Which one happens first? WebComponentsReady or dom-change?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I just started on Polymer. There seems to be two events indicating content is ready:

```
// Listen for template bound event to know when bindings
// have resolved and content has been stamped to the page
app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
  console.log('Our app is ready to rock!');
});

// See https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
});
```

I wonder if it is necessary to wrap them together and put the code inside, to make sure that the document is fully loaded before doing any script, for example:

```
app.addEventListener('dom-change', function() {
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    // scripts go here
  });
});
```

However, I don't know what is the correct way to do so in all browsers. If WebComponentsReady happens before dom-change, the inside script never execute.

Heck, this might not even be necessary because the polymer-starter-kit doesn't wrap them together. In that case, which types of script should go inside `dom-change` event and which types of script should go inside `WebComponentsReady` event?

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763690/polymer-and-webcomponentsready-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native `ready` callback as [described here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method).

```
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'example-element',
      properties: {...},
      ready: function() {
        // access a local DOM element by ID using this.$
        this.$.header.textContent = 'Hello!';
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```