# Polymer - Accessing Root Element

Tags: polymer

I'm learning Polymer. I've been trying to integrate Polymer into an existing page. In an attempt to do that, I have the following:

```
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
          <iron-signals on-iron-signal-update-greeting="_updateGreeting">
          <div>[[ greeting ]]</div>
        </template>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" click="testClick();">Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function testClick() {
        this.fire('iron-signal', { name: 'updateGreeting', data: { value: 'Hello at ' + (new Date().getMinutes()) } });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

This is a learning exercise regarding `iron-signals`. I understand how to use iron-signals within a Polymer app. However, I'm trying to fire off a signal from outside of the app. When I do this, I get the following error:

```
this.fire is not a function
```

I understand why I'm getting the error. However, I guess I don't understand how to get a reference to the actual Polymer object so that I can call the `fire` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for Polymer to upgrade the elements. See [Polymer and WebComponentsReady event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763690/polymer-and-webcomponentsready-event)

When you do this inside an element your code isn't called before Polymer is ready. Outside you have to take care yourself.

Comment: Even when I wait for WebComponentsReady, `this.fire(...)` still causes a `this.fire is not a function` error.

Comment: I see. `fire()` is a function of a Polymer element. If your code doesn't run inside an element, `fire()` is not available. You can use `dispatchEvent()` instead https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent. It depends on what you actually want to achieve. You can also `querySelector()` a Polymer element and call `fire()` on the element.